# Adding background image to a new window in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def func_checkprice():
    try:
        global product_link
        
        product_link = link.get()
        page =requests.get(product_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        product_name = soup.find(class_='_35KyD6').get_text()
        price = soup.find(class_='_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1').get_text()
        print(product_name ,price, ctime())
        product_window = Tk()
        product_window.geometry("200x200")
        back_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("388275.jpg"))
        back_label1 = Label(product_window, image=back_img1)
        back_label1.place(x=0, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)
        details_name = Label(product_window , text=product_name, wraplength=120)
        details_price = Label(product_window , text=price, wraplength=120)
        details_name.grid(row=0,column=0)
        details_price.grid(row=0,column=1)
        okay_button = Button(product_window, text="Okay", command=product_window.destroy)
        okay_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=10, pady=5)
        link.delete(0,END)
    except:
        popup = messagebox.showerror("Error","Invalid Link")
```

The background code works fine for the root window. This product_window opens when I click on a button on the root window. I just can't add the background to the new window tried everything I possibly could.

Comment: `back_img1` is garbage-collected (yes, even though it is used in the label). You have to keep another reference to it.

Comment: sorry, what? Didn't get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either say `global back_img1` on top of your function to keep a reference or you can also say `back_label1.image=back_img1`. This will keep the image from being garbage collected by pythons garbage collector.

And i assume your `product_window` the first window(parent) in your program, as your not allowed to use more than one instance of `Tk()`, if its not the main window of your program then replace `Tk()` with `Toplevel()` as those are used for referencing child windows to the parent `Tk()` window. If there is more than one instance of `Tk()` youll receive an error, that `pyimagex does not exist`

Hope it cleared your doubts.

Cheers